# Jest test failing for DrawerNavigator in a Typescript React native project

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation-drawer, ts-jest

I'm new at React Native and Typescript. I have been implementing a small project with Stack Navigation and Drawer Navigation. The project has been working well but now I have to make some unit tests. I started with a very simple one but is failing :/

This is the code for the navigation of the app:

Navigator.tsx

```js
import App from "../../App";
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, NavigationScreenProp, NavigationState, NavigationParams } from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LoginScreen from "./LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./RegisterScreen";
import MapScreen from "./MapScreen";
import BikesScreen from "./BikesScreen";
import TheftScreen from "./TheftScreen";
import RentBikeScreen from "./RentBikeScreen";
import RouteListScreen from "./RouteListScreen";
import CouponScreen from "./CouponScreen";
import strings from "../config/strings";

interface Props {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState,NavigationParams>;
}

interface State {}

export default class NavigatorContainer extends React.Component<Props, State> {  
  render() {

  const DrawerStack = 
  createDrawerNavigator({     
    Map: MapScreen,      
    Bikes: BikesScreen,  
    Theft: TheftScreen,
    RouteList: RouteListScreen,
    Coupon: CouponScreen   
  })


  DrawerStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];

    const headerTitle = 
    routeName == "Map" ? strings.CONSULT_ROUTE : 
    routeName == "Bikes" ? strings.BIKES_TITLE : 
    routeName == "Theft" ? strings.THEFT_REPORT_TITLE :
    routeName == "Register" ? strings.REGISTER_SCREEN_TITLE :
    routeName == "RouteList" ? strings.ROUTE_LIST_TITLE :
    routeName == "Coupon" ? strings.COUPON_TITLE : "";

    return {
      headerTitle,
      headerLeft: ({ tintColor }: {tintColor: any}) => (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}><Image
          source={require('../assets/images/drawer.png')}
          style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}        
        /></TouchableHighlight>)
    };
  };

  const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {        
      Login: {
        screen: LoginScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null 
        }      
      },   
      Register: {
        screen: RegisterScreen    
      },      
      DrawerStack: DrawerStack
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Login',
    }
  );

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
    return <AppContainer />;   
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
});
```

This is the test:

App-test.tsx

```js
/**
 * @format
 */
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

import * as renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

jest.mock('react-native', () => {
  return { 
    StyleSheet: {
      create: () => {

      }
    },
    Platform: {}
  }
});

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

When executing the tests with "yarn test" I get this:

`src/screens/Navigator.tsx:50:38 - error TS7031: Binding element 'navigation' implicitly has an 'any' type`

So I changed 'navigation' with 'navigation : NavigationScreenProp':

```js
DrawerStack.navigationOptions = (navigation : NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState,NavigationParams>) => {....
```

And the test pass!... but now when I try to go to one of the screens of the DrawerNavigator for instance MapScreen, using 'this.props.navigation.navigate('Map')' I get the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state.routes')
```

I see that the problem is in this line:

```js
const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
```

but I don't know how to solve it and don't understand why it worked only with '({ navigation })'

Any ideas?

Comment: the react version is  "react": "16.9.0", the navigation drawer version is "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3", and I'm using "jest": "^24.1.0", anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a sintax problem, I changed this:

```js
DrawerStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
```

with this:

```js
DrawerStack.navigationOptions = ({navigation} : { navigation : NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState,NavigationParams>}) => {
```